# HTML to JS Object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars to compile and get the html from the JS object. Is it possible to  transform (html) back to JS object (using handlebars or anyother library)? To be more precise; Using handlebars, I have the following template:

```
<tr>
 <td>{{qty}}</td>
 <td>{{rate}}</td>
 <td>{{gstPerc}}</td>
 <td>{{discountPerc}}</td>
 <td>{{amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

and following JS Object:

```
{
    qty : 12,
    rate : 1000,
    gstPerc : 10,
    discountPerc : 2,
    amount: 1500
}
```

after compilation using handlebars, it gets transform to simple html i.e following, for example.

```
<tr>
 <td>12</td>
 <td>1000</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>1500</td>
</tr>
```

Now what I was wondering is, Is it possible (using handlebars), to transform the given HTML back to the object?

Comment: If you face this problem a lot, you should look into using `angular` or another javascript MVC-framework that allows you to create two way bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give give data-name as    qty ,rate etc

```
var obj = getElementsByTagName('td');
$data   = {};
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
   $data[obj[i].dataset.name]  = obj[i].innerHtml;
}
```

you can do reverse process you want to populate table with object data
You can use grid control like [jqgrid](http://jqgrid.com/) for easy integration

Comment: +1 but `class` or `data-*` would be better, because `id` should be unique.

Comment: Also, kudos for not using jQuery, when it wasn't tagged.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary templates and values, this is not possible. Consider the following template:

```
<td>{{cell1}}</td><td>{{cell2}}</td>
```

and the following result:

```
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
```

Which of `cell1`, `cell2` is empty, and which contains `</td><td>`?

If you know the HTML inserted is valid and you know the template in advance, this is easy. For your specific template:

```
var table = document.createElement("table")
table.innerHTML = input
var tds = table.rows[0].cells
return {qty: tds[0].innerHTML, rate: tds[1].innerHTML ...}
```

If you know the values inserted should be numbers, you can convert them as such:

```
return {qty: +tds[0].innerHTML, rate: +tds[1].innerHTML ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use jQuery and end up with something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CDY3b/)

In your template: add classes to the `<td>` elements:

```
<table>
<tr id='someId'>
 <td class='qty'>12</td>
 <td class='rate'>1000</td>
 <td class='gstPerc'>10</td>
 <td class='discountPerc'>2</td>
 <td class='amount'>1500</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Create your object again:

```
var myObj = {};
$("#someId td").each(function() {
    var td = $(this);
    myObj[td.attr("class")] = td.text();
});

alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```